# Compare each element of an array with each other in running time O(n logn)

Tags: java, arrays, performance

I have to check for each element that whether there is any element greater than that in the array. That means, the array has to sorted in descending order. If there is any element greater than the current element is present then i have count the number as in how many numbers are present in the array which is greater than the current element i am checking for. In this way, i have to check for each and every element. And my output has to be the total number of times there was an element greater then the current element( considering each element of the array).

The problem is i have to do it in O(n logn). I can do it the naive way, but then the running time is O(n^2).

```
public class CountPairs {
       public static int countPairs(int[] arr) {
           int Pairs=0;
           for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
               for (int j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++){
                    if (arr[i] < arr[j]){
                         Pairs++;
                    }
               }
           }
           return Pairs;
      }
   }
```

For example:
System.out.println(countPairs({3,1,4,2}) should return 3.
Please help me with this one.

Comment: I would consider using a tree although there are a few ways of improving the runtime but a Binary Search Tree seems like it could work.

Comment: Are duplicates allowed in your array? Because if not, by definition all elements `list[0]`...`list[i-1]` are greater than `list[i]` for any `i` after sorting, and finding `i` for any given number using a binary search will take `log(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your array is indeed sorted, you can replace the inner loop by a binary search.
See java.util.Arrays#binarySearch.

If you aren't sure that your array is really sorted, you can check it in linear time:
if element i+1 is greater than element i, then the array isn't sorted in descending order.
At that time you can sort the array in O(n log(n)) with Arrays #sort.